# How to enable TextBox remove spaces at begin and end with input?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

TextBox is used to accept user inputs, but users maybe put space at begin or end of the input and did not realize that they put extra spaces for the data. How to remove those spaces for TextBox as generic solution and no need to put code for each TextBox?

Answer (score 1):

You could create your own textbox that inherits from textbox and overload the text property and return a trimmed string and use that custom textbox everywhere...

Something like:

```
Public Class TrimmedTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

   Public Overloads Property Text As String
       Get
          Return CStr(GetValue(TextProperty)).Trim
       End Get
       Set(value As String)
           SetValue(TextProperty, value)
      End Set
   End Property

End Class
```

Or you could just trim the text when you retrieve it from the textbox, which I'm assuming that you do retrieve it - or why have a textbox?